# Forever encoding which is just a continuous string of characters in the console for some time

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image, email, smtp

I have used SKPSSMTP for send email in background. I have refer this [code](https://github.com/jetseven/skpsmtpmessage) . I am attaching 4 images in the email below is my code for attaching image. I am receiving email successfully but
I still get the forever encoding which is just a continuous string of characters in the console and my xcode does not respond and sometimes i get request tie out error and my app gets crashed.

CODE for attaching image:

```
 NSData *vcfDataimg_1 = nil,*vcfDataimg_2= nil;

    for (int i=0; i<directoryContent.count; i++) {
        NSString *imageName=[appDel.arrdelBrushImages objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *vcfPathimg=[dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
        if (i == 0) {
            vcfDataimg_1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:vcfPathimg];
            vcfDataimg_1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"inline;\r\n\tx-unix-mode=0644;\r\n\tname=\"black.png\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                            @"attachment;\r\n\tfilename=\"black.png\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentDispositionKey,[vcfDataimg_1 encodeBase64ForData],kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"base64",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];
        }
        else {
            vcfDataimg_2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:vcfPathimg];
            vcfDataimg_2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"inline;\r\n\tx-unix-mode=0644;\r\n\tname=\"red.png\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                            @"attachment;\r\n\tfilename=\"red.png\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentDispositionKey,[vcfDataimg_2 encodeBase64ForData],kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"base64",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];
        }
    }
    testMsg.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:plainPart,vcfDataimg_1,vcfDataimg_2, nil];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [testMsg send];
```

Comment: Hello  @Andrey Chernukha  please help